# Inclined sine wave in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am able to a horizontal sine wave using the below code.

```
\draw[domain = 0:4] plot [smooth] (\x,{0.4 * sin(\x * pi/2 r)});
```

How to draw an inclined sine wave using TikZ? Something similar to the following image:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (2,0) cos (3,1) sin (4,2) -- (6,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Curve with sine function]

Comment: @ hpekristiansen, I am not able understand combinationation of `cos` and `sin` that produces the desired output. Can you please explain?

Comment: Try to delete `cos` (so that this part is not draw) - then you can see what part of the curve it draws. Basically `cos` draws a quarter of a cosine wave stretched and moved, so that the endpoints match the given coordinates. -and the same for `sin`.

Comment: @Aim You could also learn from the doc for `sin` and `cos`, which is in `pgfmanual` v3.1.9a, sec. 14.10 "The Sine and Cosine Operation".